# If $x$ is a positive integer such that $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1=379^2$, find $x$

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math

> If $x$ is a positive integer such that $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+1=379^2$, find $x$

This is a 1989 ARML problem. One, ugly way to solve this is:

> Approximate this as $x^4=379^2$, so $x\approx \sqrt{379}\approx 19$ and guess and check around there to see that $18$ works.

What's a nicer way?

**Hint**

> Difference of squares

Comment: Sorry, but are you asking the question or solving your own question?

Comment: as it happens, this is not an accident, your quartic is actually the square of a quadratic polynomial. Find that, and set it equal to your 379

Comment: @User1upon0 I know the answer. I'm just trying to share a fun problem I ran across. I just wanted to give someone else the opportunity to answer first. Self answering is not only allowed but encouraged on math.SE

Comment: @avid19: A nice problem to solve, +1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) &=379^2-1\\
&=(380)(378) \\
&=(19)(20)(18)(21).
\end{align*}

Hence it follows that $x=18$.

Comment: That was my intended solution, +1

Comment: That's nice too. +1

Answer (score 5):

**Outline**

$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) + 1 = (x^2 + 3x + 1)^2 = 379^{2}$

$(x - 18)(x + 21) = 0$

$\color{blue}{x = 18}$

Comment: Nice! I didn't see this answer. +1

Comment: @avid19  Thanks. Though my first thought (though I knew this 'well-known' factorization) was to do it by putting $x^4 = 379^{2}$ just like you.

Comment: Oh I was late . Though nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply first and last term and middle terms and take 1 on RHS. $(x^2+3x)(x^2+3x+2)=379^2-1^2$ so substitute $x^2+3x=y$ you will get a simple quadratic ie $y(y+2)=380\times 378$ which are also the factors . Get the value of $y$ and and then resubstituting $y=x^2+3x$ you will get the value of $x$ Hope you can take it from here to find $x$.

Answer (score 1):

About general solution of this equation.

$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=a^2-1$

$⇔(x^2+3x)(x^2+3x+2)=(a-1)(a+1) $

obviously
$x^2+3x=a-1 $ so,

$x=\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{5+4a}}{2}$

$a_n=1,5,11,19・・・
    =1+\sum2(n+1) 
    =1+n(n-1)+2(n-1)=n^2+n-1 $

Therefore when $a=n^2+n-1$, this equation has  one positive solution $x=n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3) +1 =(x^2 +x)(x^2 +5x +6) +1 = x^4+5x^3 +6x^2 +x^3 +5x^2 +6x +1 =x^4 +6x^3 +11x^2 +6x +1 =x^2 (x^2 +6x +9) +2x(x+3)+1 =(x(x+3) +1)^2$$