# How to solve this problem on complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ Z $ be a complex number with nonzero imaginary part such that
$$ (2Z + 1)(3Z + 1)(5Z + 1)(30 Z + 1) = 10 $$

Then compute  $$ \frac{\text {sum  of  all values  of  Z}}{\text {product  of  all  values  of  Z} } $$

Comment: Note:  the non-zero imaginary part complicates matters, as the quartic actually has two real roots.  As it stands, I think you have to factor the quartic as a product of two quadratics.

Comment: If you know the two real root of the polynomial, then you can finish quickly. I think it can be decomposed or it has two rational roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $1/2+1/30=1/3+1/5 = 2 \cdot 4/15\,$, which suggests the substitution $z = x - 4/15\,$, which gives a biquadratic in $x\,$:

$$
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot30\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(z+\frac{1}{30}\right) \\ = 900\left(x+\frac{7}{30}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{15}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{15}\right)\left(x-\frac{7}{30}\right) \\ = 900\left(x^2-\frac{7^2}{30^2}\right)\left(x^2-\frac{1}{15^2}\right) \\ = \frac{1}{225}(900x^2-49)(225x^2-1)
$$

Then $225(\text{LHS} - 10)$ factors into two qadratics, one of which has the complex roots being sought:

$$
(900x^2-49)(225x^2-1)-2250=(900 x^2 + 71) (225 x^2 - 31)
$$

Comment: you're a wizard harry

Comment: @SakethMalyala Thanks. The technique is fairly well known, and it was probably expected to be used in this case since it's no coincidence that the coefficients were chosen as they did. The symmetry is more easily recognizable and exploitable when the factors on the LHS are monic polynomials (for example [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2345609/291201)), but also applies to problems like the above (or this [other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2137384/291201)) once you get the gist of it.